# running a windows form thread while window is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form running a thread which reads a string and showing it in text boxes.

It has start - stop buttons to start showing words in the text boxes within the window `Main_Form`.

now, i need to create an opening form that handle the start stop. when you press start the same thing should happen, but `Main_Form` could be closed

you have a button to open the `Main_Form` and see the text boxes change

it only works when i type:

```
m_mf = new Main_Form();
m_mf.Show();
m_mf.start();
```

if i type

```
m_mf.Visible = false;
```

or close the Main Form window the program kills itself

Comment: Setting `Visible` should not cause the program to close unless you are trying to do that from within a new thread (in which case you 'd get an exception). Are you?

Comment: hi jon, i don't want to close the program. i want the thread within `Main_Form` to run, nevertheless the window is shows or not. i have a button in the `Opening_Form` show to the `Main_Form`

Comment: That's what I 'm saying. **`Visible = false` does not close the program either.** If your program closes that is because **you have a bug somewhere**. The bug might be that you are setting `Visible` from another thread.

Comment: if i type `m_mf.Hide();` the program works, but it's not nice because the window appears and disappears. so my question is there a way to works with the text boxes (what `Main_Form` does) without having the window appear thank you for you answers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Hide() rather than visible = false:

```
m_mf.Hide();
```

If you use `m_mf.Close();` that will completely close the program.

[This article](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Hiding_and_Showing_Forms_in_C_Sharp) might help you a little.

Comment: `Hide()` is exactly the same as setting `Visible = false`. It's in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx): *"Hiding the control is equivalent to setting the Visible property to false"*

Comment: actually m_mf.hide() works! but is there a way to make it work without showing the window popping?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to run a new form after m_mf is close, in your main function you can modify it as follows:

```
 Application.Run(new m_mf());
 Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Comment: hi, I don't want to run 2 programs, i want to run only run program. in the program.cs i want to leave it `Application.Run(new Opening_Form());`, and when pressing start in the `Opening_Form` to have the `Main_Form` thread running