# Create a program to run from the system tray

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to create a program to run from the bottom right system tray of Windows.

But I don't know where to start from?

Can someone tell \ show me where to look and examples or what commands to use \ research ?

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732294/351383, it's C# but if you have problems you can translate it to VB.NET here http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Google is really useful - a search for "VB.NET program to run from system tray" returned [Create a System Tray Application in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET).  And Visual Basic is **NOT** the same thing as VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks Guys for youre feedback I'll do some reading now :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I review the answers I note that miss the icon.

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
        NotifyIcon1.Icon = SystemIcons.Application
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Verificador corriendo"
        NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Verificador corriendo"
        NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
        'Me.Hide()
        ShowInTaskbar = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.DoubleClick
    'Me.Show()
    ShowInTaskbar = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 19):

Add a `NotifyIcon` to the main windows form.
Use the `Resize` event in `Form` to control when to show the `NotifyIcon` and hide the form:

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
                NotifyIcon1.Visible = true
                Me.Hide()
                NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Hi from right system tray"
                NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Use the events in NotifyIcon to show the form again:

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.DoubleClick
        Me.Show()
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

You can download a full example in [AutoDNIE](https://code.google.com/p/autodni-e/downloads/detail?name=AutoDNIE-src-0.7.2.1.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges) google code project

Comment: Thanks Guys I will give it a go when I can

Comment: Thanks worked great!! Just don't do what I did and try using it without an icon... it won't work.

Comment: thanks @DanBarber for the tip. for those who don't know where to add icon. go to your **notify icon** component in design and in **properties** window set an .ico file. I didn't know what he meant at first until I tried the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
Sub ToggleHide()
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    Else
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not use the system tray.

Comment: The code can be used anywhere, place the "ToggleHide()" sub in the event for NotifyIcon double click...