# Minimize and Hide Winform on Form Load

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

I have a Windows Form in a C# program with the `FormBorderStyle` set to `FixedToolWindow`.

The window doesn't have the normal control box, but the user can still minimize it from a menu. There is also a setting for the window to start in a minimized state.

When the user clicks the minimize button it called the following function:

```
private void minimizeWindow()
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;            
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.Hide();
}
```

The window becomes a small box in the bottom left of the screen, then disappears (from the `this.hide` call).
When the same function is called from within the `Form_Load` method (when the setting is to start minimized) it minimizes but does not disappear.

My guess is that because I am hiding the form before reaching the end of `Form_Load` it is being shown again when it reaches the end of the method. Is there any way to ensure the form hides when it is loaded (it is maximised again from a system tray icon)?

Edit: Included all code from form load

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Left = windowXPos;
    this.Top = windowYPos;
    sysTrayIcon.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(sysTrayIcon_MouseDoubleClick);
    sysTrayIcon.BalloonTipText = "Timers Running";
    this.sysTrayIcon.Icon = this.Icon;
    sysTrayIcon.Visible = true;
    sysTrayIcon.ShowBalloonTip(500);
    Start();  //sets up timers
    if (startMinimized)
    {
        minimizeWindow();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the Form_Shown event

Comment: Would it be possible to start the program minimized.  Then check during the `Form_Load` if the setting is set to not start minimized, restore it.

Comment: My guess is that you are using ShowDialog() versus just Show().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be best to change your logic slightly, and instead of showing the form at all, create an instance of it (`var foo = new MyForm()`) but don't call `.Show()` so it will never be shown until triggered from your system tray icon.

Comment: So make a change in Program.cs so it doesn't call `Application.Run(new MainProgramForm());`?

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray