# How to set windows.form's start position to bottom?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Is there any way to make "StartPosition" Starts to **"Bottom"**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to [start it minimized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35608239/107625)?

Comment: No i just want it open from bottom not above

Comment: It is not clear what you'd like to achive.

Comment: @koviroli i edited it

Comment: Still not clear (to me).

Comment: @UweKeim someone already understood it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use location property.

```
this.Location = new Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                          (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height));

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = ...;
}
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: below the initializecomponent(); ?

Comment: As a note, you *should* have something like: `Screen screen = Screen.FromHandle(this.Handle); this.Location = new Point((screen.WorkingArea.Width ...);` in `Form.Load()` or `OnHandleCreated()`. You're supposing that the application main Window is opened in the Primary screen, which may not be the case.